# Posting previously published content on Arxiv

Tags: copyright, arxiv, license

I have some previously published work in the computer vision domain, and would like to upload them to arXiv to provide greater accessibility.

How can I go about finding which licence statement to select for the particular conferences my work was published in (CVPR & ECCV)?

Comment: When you published the paper, you likely signed a copyright agreement with the conference.  It should explain what rights you do and don't have.  Then you will know what rights you can or cannot license to arXiv and its users.

Comment: See also here: http://arxiv.org/help/license If in doubt, ask the publisher if you are allowed to post to the arXiv.

Comment: As a meta-comment about license selection on the arXiv, you should never choose anything but the default license unless you are certain that you have the legal right to do so.  The issue is that all the other licenses offer readers the right to re-use your work in various ways.  If you're not actually in a position to offer them this right, then you are putting them in a terribly awkward position (either the readers, the publisher, or both are guaranteed to end up unhappy).  The default license is enormously more likely to be allowed, and most users never even need to consider the others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the copyright agreement you signed when you published the paper. It usually states under which conditions uploading the paper to other repositories is acceptable. Usually, you are only allowed to upload the "[authors version](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/65437/26477)" (or some variant thereof), which usually needs to contain a specific phrase like (in the case of the [ACM](http://www.acm.org/publications/policies/copyright_policy)):

> © ACM, YYYY. This is the author's version of the work. It is posted here by permission of ACM for your personal use. Not for redistribution. The definitive version was published in PUBLICATION, {VOL#, ISS#, (DATE)} http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/nnnnnn.nnnnnn"

There is also a web service that makes this a bit easier to figure out: [SHERPA/RoMEO](http://www.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/index.php). There you can put in the publisher / journal, and it will give you a human-readable summary of their policies (for example, [here](http://www.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/search.php?id=21&fIDnum=|&mode=simple&la=en) is the page for the ACM). But note that [publisher policies change](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/65531/submitting-acm-conference-papers-to-arxiv), and the binding version is the one you signed when you published the paper, so the data from SHERPA/RoMEO may be incorrect.

Note that, in my experience, almost all publishers allow uploading to an "institutional repository", so even if ArXiv may be disallowed, you can still make your work accessible via your institutional repository (if your institution has one) or your homepage. But, again, check the specific policies that apply to you on that.

Finally: I am not a lawyer, but as I understand it, since you no longer own the copyright on the paper, you cannot put it under a creative commons license (which is an option on ArXiv). So, you'll have to take the [minimal license they allow](https://arxiv.org/licenses/nonexclusive-distrib/1.0/license.html), which only gives them permission to distribute your work (If someone else knows this better than I do, feel free to correct me in the comments or edit the answer).

Also, you can always just ask the publisher if you want to be extra sure, but in my experience, this may be a long process (I waited for over a week for a reply by the ACM, and am have now been waiting for over a month for a reply to a followup question).